# MySQL query to get date that total visit count goes over specific sum

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that stores daily metrics for different websites. An example of the table:

DomainStats

```
|DomainId |     StatPullTime    | Visits |
+---------+---------------------+--------+
    1     | 2013-06-20 00:00:00 |  500   |
    1     | 2013-06-21 00:00:00 |  500   |
    1     | 2013-06-22 00:00:00 |  500   |
    1     | 2013-06-23 00:00:00 |  500   |
    1     | 2013-06-24 00:00:00 |  500   |
    1     | 2013-06-25 00:00:00 |  500   |
    1     | 2013-06-26 00:00:00 |  500   |
    1     | 2013-06-27 00:00:00 |  1000  |
```

So I need a create a query that will start from today's date and go back each day until the sum of the visits is greater than 2999.

In the example table, it would return 2013-06-23.

This is the closest I can think of:

```
SELECT SUM(Visits) AS Visits, StatPullTime
FROM DomainStats
GROUP BY StatPullTime HAVING SUM(Visits) > 2999
```

Comment: Do you need to group this by DomainId as well?

Comment: This will be difficult to do in pure SQL, since you will really have to loop through the records.  That implies a cursor.  Could you code a solution in a procedural language instead?

Comment: @Barmar Ya I do. Sorry, didn't include that in OP.

Comment: @BillGregg I suppose I could, although MySQL would be the cleanest for what I am doing. If it's not possible in SQL I may resort to that instead.

Comment: Its just the nature of your problem.  You are essentially saying "While (Sum < 2999) {Go Back 1 Day, Sum += Today's Count} return Today".  That's really not what SQL is good for.  But you can use a cursor and make it happen, or a regular while loop.

Comment: @Kyle, you say "go back each day until the sum is ...." But what do you expect on the output? Can you please update your question and write the exact output expected?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it in pure SQL, but it's likely to be very inefficient if the records go back very far.

```
SELECT a.DomainId DomainId, a.StatPullTime StatPullTime, SUM(b.Visits) Visits
FROM DomainStats a
JOIN DomainStats b ON a.DomainId = b.DomainId AND b.StatPullTime >= a.StatPullTime
GROUP BY DomainId, StatPullTime
HAVING Visits < 3000
ORDER BY DomainId, StatPullTime DESC
```

The reason this is slow is because it performs an O(N<sup>2</sup>) self-join. @Tomas's answer is more practical.

Comment: Barmar, thank for your appreciation and comments. I intuitively feel your query could still be somehow optimized, though I don't know how. Keep trying! :-)

Comment: Theoretically, a smart query optimizer could determine that it's equivalent to yours. But we're talking about MySQL, which doesn't even do `WHERE IN (SELECT ...)` well.

Comment: you should add `a.`: `GROUP BY a.DomainId, a.StatPullTime`, the same for ORDER BY clause. In the select clause you don't need the aliases for these columns.

Comment: I think in this case it would have not been possible to optimize it - you force the SQL to compute all possible sums (very clever trick BTW, though brutal computation time), and I think he has no chance to realize that this can be simplified... And now I am afraid that any optimizations are out of the scope of standard SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Linear, one pass solution, for MySQL only (i.e. very efficient but not compliant to strict SQL):

```
set @sum_visits := 0, @domain_id = -1;

SELECT 
    @sum_visits := if(@domain_id = DomainId, @sum_visits, 0) + Visits AS SUM_Visits,
    @domain_id := DomainId as DomainId,
    StatPullTime,
FROM DomainStats
GROUP BY DomainId, StatPullTime
ORDER BY DomainId asc, StatPullTime desc
HAVING SUM_Visits <= 2999
```

Comment: Can this solution be adapted to per-DomainId sum?

Comment: @Barmar yes, it can, it would still be one-pass - just sort by both DomainId, StatPullTime and reset when DomainId changes. Was it in the OP's requirements? I missed it.

Comment: See his response to my question in the comment.

Comment: So this still calculates all the sums going back to the beginning of the database, it just doesn't show them because of the `HAVING` clause. BTW, your `HAVING` clause is backwards. He wants to *stop* when the sum is > 2999

Comment: @Barmar I must admit this is not clear to me, as the OP didn't really specify this. He just said " go back each day until the sum is ...". But he didn't specify what he wants to output!

Comment: Maybe now it is correct? I don't actually understand OP's requirements, until he replies.

Comment: Actually, what I suspecthe really wants, and was in the first version of my answer, is just the date where it went over 2999 -- he wants to answer the question "How long did it take for each site to reach 3,000 hits?"

Comment: See in his question where it says _In the example table, it would return 2013-06-23._

Comment: Aaah, that would be even more difficult for us ;-)

Comment: Put your query into a subquery, and then use `MIN(StatsPullTime) GROUP BY DomainId` in the outer query.

Comment: @Barmar yes I know but that makes it very ugly, I prefer to avoid that and keep the answer simple ;-)